# Why won't a ferry VIP mission complete?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

It seems like a bug: I accepted the mission months ago. I recently came back, carried out the missions, but the missions did not complete. Furthermore, the VIPs are no longer able to be added to new spacecraft. There aren't any spacecraft floating around in space with them, either. They're just missing.

How can I complete the mission -- or, if this is indeed a bug, how can I fix it or work around it?

Answer (score 5):

You can always complete a contract using the debug menu. Press `alt-F12` to open it, then go to the Contracts tab and click the "complete" button. You still get all the rewards and everything just as if you had completed it the normal way (which in this case you have anyway, you're just working around the bug).

Comment: gave a +1 for this as it does answer the question  - how can I work around it.

Answer (score 2):

I only have a partial answer, sadly.  I don't know how to fix your bug.  But as for why the mission did not complete upon returning home, its not obvious at first but the wording of the contract often specifies how you're supposed to return home.  If the wording of the tourist's itinerary  specifically says "land on Kerbin", then you must finish the journey on land.  If it ends with "splash down on Kerbin", then you must finish the journey in the water.  I've had to get in the habit of saving some time before reentry and adjusting my incoming trajectory several times to get the "correct" ending to the mission.